# How to Read the Barcode in image using Python 3.6 without using Zbar

Tags: django, python-3.6, barcode

I am New to Barcode Reader i found some Tutorial about Zbar and which seems to not support in ZBAR. I like to raed the Barcode in a Image and extract the Data in it.

This is What is Actually Tried.

```py
def detect_barcode(request):
    try:
        import pyqrcode
        import zbarlight
        qr = pyqrcode.create("HORN O.K. PLEASE.")
        qr.png("download.png", scale=6)
        import qrtools
        from qrtools.qrtools import QR
        from qrtools.qrtools import Image,BOM_UTF8
        qr = qrtools.QR()
        qr.decode("download.png")
        True
        print(qr.data);
        qr.data
    except Exception as e:
        test = str(e)
```

I Need to Decode the Barcode and extract the Data. I don't like to use Zbar.

Answer (score -1):

If it helps. We have a web browser that reads barcodes. No changes to your page are needed.
You can embed barcode scanning in your page and handle the result with JavaScript if you need more control.

Scan to Web